# Angular JS: how to href inside of a ng-if depeding of the extension

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<a title="{{::item.title}}" 
   data-ng-click="vm.selectedShareItem = item;
      vm.curShareIdx = (vm.numberBeforePaginate * vm.currentPage) + $index;
      vm.showPopin = true;">
```

This code will open the following div:

```
<div class="popin-full popin-share" data-ng-if="vm.showPopin"
     data-ng-click="vm.showPopin = false">
```

What I want is to open a pop-up if the file ends with ".vid" but if it ends with ".aspx" it a page to "x" location.

Is it possible to do that?

To diferentiate extensions, i inserted the following code:

```
vm.commonPageExtensions = 'aspx$';

vm.commonVideoExtensions = '3g2$|3gp$|amv$|asf$|avi$';
```

EDIT: To get the URL I have the following snip

```
href="{{vm.selectedShareItem.path}}"
```

Comment: It's best to put complex logic in the controller and then simply call a method from your view. Should be pretty easy once you've moved the logic to the controller.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Lex, but we can't separate these things. Is there any other solutions?